# how to insert textview with ImageView inside EditText in android dynamically?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-custom-view

I am trying to insert a textview with an imageview inside a Edittext as in below .

[image]

can anyone pls give me ideas about how to implement it or something.

thanks :)

update: the textviews in the edittext will vary dynamically

Answer (score 0):

To show textview in android edittext you can try this code..

```
EditText your_edittext =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
   your_edittext.setHint("Your  Text");
```

Now to add image you can do it like this..

```
Your_edittext.setCompoundDrawables(null,  null,     getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_image), null
```